# Counting occurrences for each row and update to new column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table: [image]

I need count the occurrence of the same line in column CloseTime and write the number of occurrences in the last column Count with where clause for Item and same account.

My single select for concrete Item and account is

```
SELECT CloseTime, COUNT(*) AS CloseTime
FROM Statement 
WHERE Account = 2013169 AND item = 'eurusd'
GROUP BY CloseTime
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

It is possible to count in one update query?

Comment: Why do you need to *store* this redundant data in a column? This just means you'll constantly have to run this query to keep it up to date, whenever a row is inserted, deleted, updated...

Comment: Because I can not get everything in one select. Its very difficult.

Comment: Can you show what you want as the output of your select?

Comment: The result would show me all the incidences CloseTime for each Item and at the same time count the Profit

Comment: I'm asking for an example, based on the screen shot you've posted, not a word problem.

Comment: Example like this http://i.dogportal.sk/images/VvJt8.png

Comment: How is that screen shot related to the screen shot above? I don't see any dates that match at all.

Comment: Because the occurrence is already counted in column CloseTime, it's possible a bad name for the column.Better name for Int desc in screenshot is CloseTimeOccurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your use case, this is probably not a good idea.  You would be better off creating "Count" as a calculated column or leaving it off the base table entirely and creating a view that included the count column.  Also, I would generally avoid trying to have a column with a name that is also a reserved word, like Count.

However, if you really want to do it, you can do it in one query.  Just to make sure we are on the same page, I belive you were trying to group by only the closetime and the account and item will not be included in the group by (so, it will be counted if same close time and different item), but want to be able to update only the target account and item.

In that case, it would look roughly like

```
with cte1 as 
(select 
closetime, COUNT(*) as numCount
from dbo.[statement]
group by closetime)

update dbo.[statement]
set [count] = cte1.numCount
from  dbo.[statement] as sd
join cte1 
    on sd.closetime = cte1.closetime
where
    sd.account = <your account num>
    and sd.item = <your item>
```

---

EDIT:

If I understand from the comments what you want correctly, then you could use a query like:

```
with cte1 as 
(select 
closetime, COUNT(*) as numCount
from dbo.[statement]
group by closetime)

select sd.*, --I normally  would advise not using * in production
cte1.numCount as [Count]
from statement as sd
join cte1
   on sd.closetime = cte1.closetime
where
        sd.account = <your account num>
        and sd.item = <your item>
```

while this does use a CTE, it is a single SQL statement and will display the counts for the selected account num and item by their closetime.

Comment: I know that this is not a good idea. But I can not get all the information on the number of multi Count in one query.

Comment: @nørdic if we know what output you want from your hard-to-read screen shot, we can show you how to get the result in a single query. Think about the goal, not about the only way you think you can reach the goal. There's a reason multiple people are telling you this is a bad idea, but you seem convinced that you're stuck with your bad idea, and I'm not sure I understand why.

Comment: I know. My goal is to get data from those calculated in the screenshot CloseTime occurrence for each Item and Account column. I am sad, because I was trying to get over there and update CALCULATE otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for edit, is better way, but with any errors Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
The multi-part identifier "sd.closetime" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
The multi-part identifier "sd.account" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
The multi-part identifier "sd.item" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'st'.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in there where I aliased the table name.

Comment: It works,Thank you. But contains small error. Otherwise it's exactly what I needed. For a while the inscription on an error.

Comment: This is correct version for me, Thank you very much . It works http://pastebin.com/94EQSZ1Q